# Scroll while dragging event from top to bottom of fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I have used Fullcalendar-2.0.0 plugin to built a page which shows a events on  the calendar. 
Everything is working fine. 
But just wanted to know is there any way to scroll the calendar while dragging particular  events? 
It is working while we drag event in browser but I want to do the same for mobile devices, but I am unable to make it working.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you.